# Issue when displaying data from JSON onload of the page

Tags: angularjs, json

```
I have included my code in http://codepen.io/sajoambattu/pen/MbezNa
```

By default need to display the first related call plans data(first color, first memory) in all sections(apple, samsung, sony).

Now it's working after onclick of the memory and color section which is correct for onclick function. My only requirement is to display the first related call plans data after loading the page.

Example:

In apple section, need to display 16gb and first color(Silver) related call plans.

In samsung section, need to display 32gb and first color(Gold platinum) related call plans.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it fixed or still you have issue? Seems your link is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init() method and load the first element

```
<p ng-repeat="x in v | orderBy:'memory'" ng-init="loadFirstItem()" ng-click="showDataMemory(((x.memory+' ')+(x.presales_name)).split(' ').join('-').replace('(','').replace(')',''))">{{x.memory}}GB</p>
```

Please find useful plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/PpWrCJALovStcE4FRM33?p=preview